# Excel 2010 Clear contents from a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet that has a table in range A4:BD4 (this is the first row of the data. I want to clear the data but leave the table intact. I do not know how many rows are of data are in the table, it will vary.

The table itself has a few more columns but I do not want to remove the data from them just from A thru BD. BE for instance needs to hold the data.

Here is code that removes all the data from all the columns:

```
For Each mySheet In wb.Sheets
   For Each myTable In mySheet.ListObjects

      myTable.DataBodyRange.ClearContents
   Next myTable
Next mySheet
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work; you can use offset and resize together  to skip over whichever areas you want to leave intact:

```
Sub ResetTables()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each mySheet In wb.Sheets
    For Each tbl In mySheet.ListObjects
        With tbl.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, 0)
            .Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count - 1).Columns.ClearContents
        End With
    Next tbl
Next mySheet

End Sub
```

I think you may find this resource helpful if you want additional help:
http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables